# How to make this Gradient effect decline fade on a mesh

Tags: modeling

How can I make this effect on a mesh which seems like there is a sloping gradient. But I need for the face to be flat and not on a skewing angle. on the left is what I'm trying to achieve, its done in photoshop. And on the right is the attempt I'm making in Blender.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>`I`</kbd> Inset top face of a cube, subdivide (e.g. using <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to only subdivide on one axis) for better curvature if not using linear falloff (which I'll actually use here), select the subdivided faces of the inset again, and <kbd>`I`</kbd> inset it again, but this time make sure to not scale it down. <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`I`</kbd> invert selection, <kbd>H</kbd> hide to avoid affecting that geometry by the next step, <kbd>O</kbd> enable proportional editing, select an edge on one side and <kbd>G</kbd> move it down (might want to increase the influence radius with $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬇\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel down*). <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> reveal hidden geometry:

[image]

Move your light source beyond the lowered side, increase the light's radius, make sure you have enough samples:

[image]

Cycles 1024 samples, 'sharp' falloff and area lamp:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, video recording helped so much! Cheers!

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me how you make such long gif files weighing no more than 2 mb?

Comment: @ugorek There are many tricks, in this case I actually just recorded with ShareX and was only barely above limit (~2.06 MB something like that). So I used https://ezgif.com/optimize and just decreased compression to minimum. There is automatic removal of frames and manual removal of frames, you can crop, scale down… I often render to PNG series, use http://apngasm.sourceforge.net/ to make APNG, compress with https://tinypng.com/ , it doesn't work on BSE then, so I use ezgif.com to convert to GIF. Also, when recording, make sure you have as much static, flat color as possible.